# What was the "raw bytes format" that random.org used to have

Tags: random, hex, byte

The "raw bytes module" on random.org is disabled (http://www.random.org/bytes/), and I need to know the output format they used to have.
More specificly: I have a program using 1024 raw hex bytes from random.org and I need to implement this feature.

What was the format they used to have? Possible formats I can think of are:

- 0x1a 0x1b
- #1a #1b
- 1a 1b
- 1a1b
- .......

There are many possibilities... Who may help me?

Comment: If you can't get data now/again, why ask/care? If you will be able to get data again in the future, simply implement everything else - feed it whatever fake format you like, the internal algorithms should *only* deal with the byte sequence and not the text used a serialization format - and change/implement the reader later.

Comment: As I said I am implementing this to be independent from random.org. So I am programming an alternate solution - if I only knew the exact format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://archive.org/web/ to retrieve an old web page that doesn't exists anymore.

For example: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.random.org/bytes/ (sorry but there is a silly problem with the `*` in the url even if I use the percent encoding code, so copy and paste it, don't click on it)

Then pick a backup at a date which seems to be good.

If it's not ok, go to previous page and pick another backup.

For example I chose 2014/03/01 [and voilà](http://web.archive.org/web/20140301191747/http://www.random.org/bytes/)

If you're lucky you can even use the form of the backuped page: [here's the result](http://web.archive.org/web/20130823202807/http://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h) with the defaults params.

Comment: Great one! So it was "1a 1b". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yaron You're welcome. The way back machine isn't often usefull, but when you need it, it's extremely usefull ;)